# No default drag image on Firefox 67

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, drag-and-drop

I just set a simple `div`'s `draggable` attribute to `true` like so:

```css
#aDiv {
    width: 400px;
    height: 550px;
    background-color: blue;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id = "aDiv" draggable="true"></div>
```

When I drag the item, I see drag images on Chrome, Opera, Edge and Internet Explorer 11, but none on Firefox.

Why isn't there a default drag image for draggable items on Firefox? Am I missing something?

I am using Firefox 67 on Windows 10.

**UPDATE**

Jaydeep's comment to the original question has a link to an answer, which suggests that we must provide a `dragstart` event handler for the draggable element and must also set some data on the `event.dataTransfer` object in order for Firefox to start displaying the drag image. So, I changed my code as follows but it has no effect on Firefox still. Any ideas why?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#aDiv").on("dragstart", function(event) {
        event.dataTransfer.setData("text", "foo");
        event.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = "move";
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id = "aDiv" draggable="true"></div>
```

Comment: check [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/214613/draggable-true-is-not-working-in-firefox-for-lightning-component)

Comment: @Jaydeep Thank you. I am testing out what you said. Meanwhile, please post that as an answer so it will help others also.

Comment: @Jaydeep Nope. No effect. I am adding more details to the question.

Comment: I have updated the answer and tested in firefox 24(cant download latest one)

Answer (score 0):

"To make an element draggable set draggable attribute to "true". However this is not enough to make elements draggable in Firefox. You need to locate the dragstart event and set some data on the DataTransfer object:"

```js
document.getElementById('aDiv').addEventListener('dragstart', function(e){
  e.dataTransfer.setData('text', 'foo');
});

function dragstart(component, event, helper) {
     component.set("v.dragid", event.target.dataset.dragId);
     event.dataTransfer.setData('Text', component.id);
}
```

```css
#aDiv {
    width: 400px;
    height: 550px;
    background-color: blue;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id = "aDiv" draggable="true"></div>
```

Reference taken from [Here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/214613/draggable-true-is-not-working-in-firefox-for-lightning-component)